# Width <textarea> stays same until 'Content/site.css' is removed

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, css

My final goal is to have two "textArea" elements parallel to each other. Each "textArea" should occupy 45% of the screen.  Problem that I am facing is, when I include  'Content/site.css' in _LayOut.cshml, width of "textArea"  elements always stays the same. I tried changing the width of "textArea" in CSS but that had no effect. Please see the code below.

site.css has the code to restrict the width of "textArea". I commented that code; and tried changing the width of "textArea" and that had no effect. Then I removed the site.css completely. Then width of "textArea" started responding to the changes made in CSS.

```
//Index.cshtml
<div id="d1">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
         <div>
        <p>
            <textarea id="T1"></textarea>
        </p>
        <p>
            <textarea id="T2"></textarea>
        </p>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
             </div>
    }
</div>

//CSS
    body 
    {
        width: 95%;
    }

    #d1
    {
        border-color: blue;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #T1
    {
        border-color: red;
        padding: 10px;
        float: left;
        width: 45%;
    }

    #T2
    {
        border-color: green;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 45%;
    }

///_Layout.cshtml
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

        </head>
        <body>
                @RenderBody()
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
        </body>
    </html>

(BundleConfig)
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/s1.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css"
                  //"~/Content/site.css"
```

Comment: Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your elements

Comment: Can you also share the code which you commented but that had no effect? Also the code from site.css which you seem affecting your css code?

Comment: @Ravi Site.css has a code to restrict the width of text-area to 285px. I commented it out but had no effect. But I excluded the whole CSS file from the Bundle and that helped, means text-area became 100%. I got same results on two machines using different projects.

Comment: @Stephen I tried your suggestion with no positive output. But your suggestion solved some other problem that I was having. I was unable to make two DIV tags stand in parallel. Your suggestion helped in that but not making text-area 100%. In the end, I removed Site.css and that solved the text-area issue.

Answer (score 0):

something is overriding your css. try addind `!important` after your css so it dosent get overridden.like :

```
T1{
  width: 45% !important;
 }
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and that had no effect. Thanks for responding.